# Full Page Smooth Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I'm using this code to use smooth scrolling in my website ([demo](http://jsbin.com/EHAXeWo/2/edit)):

```
$("#click-me").click(function(){
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: window.screen.availHeight
  }, 200);
});
```

I'm trying to scroll so exactly the height of the page. However, it seems to scroll past this point. I've tried putting in "100%" as a value, but it didn't work.

What is causing this problem, and what should I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working correctly but unless you add this (or account for padding and margin on body), the result is slightly off.

```
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bb9ux/2/ (non-working version: http://jsfiddle.net/bb9ux/3/ )

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Scroll to particular div:

```
$("#click-me").click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#scroll-here').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gyrT7/3/)

Comment: Wow, two great answers. This is making deciding which answer to accept a tough decision. :)

Comment: +1 While this still isn't exactly what I was asking for, I think there are times when this will be useful for me in other projects. Thanks!